# How do I use this existing user database and implement user authentication in a new project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passwords

I've taken over an existing project and in charge of creating a new frontend from scratch; I've decided to go with a simple Vue/Node.JS project.

There is an existing Postgres DB that contains the users with all their encrypted passwords and salts. I am extremely unfamiliar with user authentication, but I need to implement it into our new project.

The previous developer used Ruby on Rails to create the existing project, and used something called [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth), and also the basic Ruby on Rails authentication (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).

My question is: is there a Node.JS equivalent library in which I can use to authenticate the existing users?

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at `Passport.js`, it's a well-known package to deal with an authentication. It has so-called `strategies` to work with different kinds of authentication mechanisms (for instance to authenticate in Facebook, Google and so on).

Comment: What sort of "strategy" am I to use if I already have existing password hashes and salts in place?

Comment: passport-local http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/ suits for this